# How can I skip to a certain point in the game?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

When Arkham City was released, there was a bug that when you exit the game your savegame files disappear.

I heard about the problem and I played the game without exiting.  At that point the fix was unknown, but now it is solved.  I already played most of the game but at one point the game just had to crash.

I fixed the problem now but I don't want to play all over again. **I'm looking for a way to skip directly to that point in the game** (somewhere around battling Mr. Freeze).

Up to now I've found savegames for PS3 (I have the PC version), and tried cheats from Arkham Asylum(modified), but neither helped.

Comment: I could see this sort of request coming up for pretty much any game, and I think save-finding is pretty much just Google skills and doesn't take advantage of the site's expertise.  Voted to close as Not Constructive, though I do sympathize with this situation.

Comment: @MatthewRead save-finding *is* just Google-skills; but I think the problem to be solved here actually goes deeper than this, see [this meta-discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3344/consistency-in-question-closures-regarding-asking-about-downloading-game-saves). So I've edited it in a way I hope will make it worthy to be open again.

Comment: @Oak Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that there is no way to skip to a specific part of the game through any official cheat or function built into the game.

The only way that anyone has had moderate success in reaching a point in the game without earning it is through save game sharing. This solution is not without problems.

I've quoted the relevant issue from a post on the Steam Forums regarding this save swapping issue:

> Your actual save files are stored in Steam\userdata\\57400\remote.
>   However, the catch is, these files are encrypted using a special key.
>   This key is generated when you first log in to Games for Windows Live
>   on your PC. However, despite being generated when you log in, if you
>   logged in on a different computer or cleared your GFWL data on your
>   computer and re-logged in, it would make a different key, thus
>   invalidating your save files.

The proposed solution and follow up discussion is here: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2331974

Be aware the solution did not work for everyone, and should be regarded as experimental.